# RegOpenKeyEx returns error 87 in MASM64

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm

I am writing small application in MASM64 (ML64.exe). One of the functions is setting value in registry. I started with opening the key but there is an error.

Function RegOpenKeyEx returns error 87, and GetLastError returns 0x36B7.

My code:

```
extrn ExitProcess : proc
extrn MessageBoxA : proc
extrn RegOpenKeyExA : proc
extrn RegSetValueExA : proc
extrn RegCloseKey : proc
extrn GetLastError : proc

.const
HKEY_CURRENT_USER equ 80000001h
KEY_SET_VALUE equ 2
KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY equ 4
KEY_WOW64_64KEY equ 0100h
KEY_WRITE equ 00020006h
REG_SZ equ 00000001h

.data
hReg dq 0
szRegKeyName db "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",0

.code

    Main proc
        sub rsp, 30h
        lea rax, hReg
        push rax
        mov r9, KEY_SET_VALUE+KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY+KEY_WOW64_64KEY
        mov r8, 0
        lea rdx, szRegKeyName
        mov rcx, HKEY_CURRENT_USER
        call RegOpenKeyExA ;returns 87
        call GetLastError ;returns 0x36B7
        add rsp, 30h

        xor rcx, rcx
        call ExitProcess
    Main endp
end
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance for Your help.

Comment: You are not using the x64 abi correctly, you can't ignore the shadow space.  Write this code in C first and look at the machine code that the compiler generates.

Comment: Aside, it is pointless to call GetLastError. The return value is the error code. Read the documentation.

Comment: @HansPassant So how to fix this code? Do You know what is wrong?

Comment: You also forgot the [unwind codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235241.aspx) in the pdata section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you incorrect operate with stack. your main error - `push rax` really you setup here not 5-th argument but nothing. and 5-th argument was random value in stack. correct setup 5-th argument - `mov [rsp+20h],rax` . look more also on stack align, and GetLastError not related here - Reg* functions return error code yorself but not setup lasterror. and not use global variable for  hReg, but allocate it in stack. examle can look like this:

```
extrn ExitProcess : proc
extrn MessageBoxA : proc
extrn RegOpenKeyExA : proc
extrn RegSetValueExA : proc
extrn RegCloseKey : proc

.const
HKEY_CURRENT_USER equ 80000001h
KEY_SET_VALUE equ 2
KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY equ 4
KEY_WOW64_64KEY equ 0100h
KEY_WRITE equ 00020006h
REG_SZ equ 00000001h

.data
szRegKeyName db "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",0

.code

hReg equ 28h

    test proc
        sub rsp, 38h
        lea rax,[rsp+hReg]
        mov [rsp+20h],rax
        mov r9, KEY_SET_VALUE+KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY+KEY_WOW64_64KEY
        mov r8, 0
        lea rdx, szRegKeyName
        mov rcx, HKEY_CURRENT_USER
        call RegOpenKeyExA
        test eax,eax
        jnz @@1
        mov rcx,[rsp+hReg]
        call RegCloseKey
@@1:
        add rsp, 38h
        ret
    test endp
end
```

Comment: Thanks @RbMm . Are there any ways to do this with `push` instruction? I always used `push` and other codes work.

Comment: @Dave - of course you use `push` . but this not very useful in x64

Comment: Thanks @RbMm again for answer. I think that I don't understand stack alignment. Parameters count + Return address must be divisible by 16. With one parameter there will be: sub rsp, 16 (1 parameter + return address). With two parameters there will be: sub rsp, 32 (2 parameters + return address + alignment) etc. I am thinking right?

Comment: @Dave - if you still not understand - 5-th argument must be at `rsp+20h` at call time. but in your code it at `rsp+0` - so `push rax` use wrong position in stack. need also `sub rsp,20h` after you do push for 5,6,7,... args also because must be rsp==16*n at call time - so different aligment will be if use say 5 or 6 args. as result push not used in x64 code. stack first down and align. and then use mov [rsp+20h+8*n],A(n+5) for arg A(n+5)

Comment: So this is the formula for calculating aligment (sub rsp, X): `rsp+20h+8*n` ? With one parameter there will be: `sub rsp, 28h`, Two parameters: `sub rsp, 30h` etc?

Comment: @Dave - no. at function begin - we need down stack on 28h+16*n (by sub, lea , push or it combination) where n=0,1,2.. then rcx:=A1, rdx:=A2, r8:=A3, r9:=A4, [rsp+20h]:=A5, [rsp+28h]:=A6,...

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: This, too, fails to account for the unwind information, as pointed out in the [comment by Raymond Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449509/regopenkeyex-returns-error-87-in-masm64#comment68146389_40449509). x64 implements table-based exception handling, and you are responsible for setting those up.

Comment: @IInspectable - application can run and without unwind information, if no exception will be. if we need exception handling - better use c/c++ and asm inserts only when really need (near 1% or less of code)